# Is this a bad C++ style or an editor error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code in a new C++ editor I'm trying out (CLion):

```
 struct screenPoint {
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        screenPoint(float x_, float y_): x{x_}, y{y_}{}
    };

    struct position {
        screenPoint ul; 
        float width = 0, height = 0;
        position(screenPoint p, float w, float h): ul{p},width{w},height{h}{}
    };
```

Near the end is the initialisation statement `ul{p}`, which I thought was a valid C++ way to use brace initialisation. However, CLion complains:

`Incompatible types in initialiser: Types 'float' and 'screenPoint' are not compatible.`

Note: there are no compiler errors or warnings, and the code works as expected.

If I change it to `ul(p)` the error goes away.

Now, I know that `screenPoint` does not have a constructor that accepts another `screenPoint` but is that necessary in initialisation like this?

Comment: @abhishek_naik as I said, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an editor error. List-initialization with an element of the same type should invoke the implicit copy constructor.

There was a core language defect ([1467](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1467)) about trying to copy aggregates, but this isn't an aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

That's CLion's problem for sure. Have it in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6939